# Multiplication of a lower and upper triangular matrix

Tags: matlab

I wanna multiply a lower triangular and an upper triangular matrix... the usual matrix multiplication is a waste because it spends so much time in multiplying zeros ... i am looking if there is a matlab specific way to save computation time .. matrices are of size of  the order of thousands

Comment: Any hand made solution is likely to be way slower than matlab.

Comment: Please show us your code and timings, thanks

Answer (score 5):

You *may* get some gains by using [SPARSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f6-12993.html) arrays, since they use less memory and don't do multiplication by zero, but they come with a bit of computational overhead.

Otherwise, I sincerely doubt that you can beat Matlab for efficiency in linear algebra manipulation by writing your own Matlab code.

Answer (score 2):

> the usual matrix multiplication is a waste because it spends so much time in multiplying zeros

So half the coefficients of each matrix are zero, which means that a naive matrix multiplication scheme would "waste" 3/4 of its time. And you want to try to recover that time by doing something more complicated?

I'd bet moderate amounts of money that you can't beat MATLAB. Its matrix routines are at the core of its computation engine. Most likely they check for zero coefficients and eliminate that "wasted" time on their own.

I'd echo @Jonas's comments, but would add that the only time you should be using sparse matrices is if the vast majority of coefficients are zero. As in >90%, rather than 50%.